# Finding an efficient algorithm based on divide-and-conquer to find a unique polynomial p(n) of a certain degree

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

Currently I am working on a problem that is hard for me to understand as I am new to algorithms.

The problem says :

Represent the polynomial $p(n) = a_0 + a_1n + a_2n^2 + · · · + a_dn^d $ of degree d by an array

P[0 . . d] containing its coefficients. Suppose you already have an algorithm capable of multiplying a polynomial of degree k by a polynomial of degree
1 in a time in O(k), as well as another algorithm capable of multiplying
two polynomials of degree k in a time in O(k log k). Let $n_1, n_2, . . . , n_d$ be integers.

Give an efficient algorithm based on divide-and-conquer to find the unique
polynomial p(n) of degree d whose coefficient of highest degree is 1, such that
$p(n_1) = p(n_2) = . . . = p(n_d) = 0$. Analyse the efficiency of your algorithm.

I don't understand where to begin and also what's the purpose of giving an algorithm that multiplies two polynomials of degree k in O(k log k) ?

Answer (score 1):

Answer polynomial is $(x-n_1)(x-n_2)...(x-n_d)$

Algo is this:

Let $P(a,b) = (x-n_a)...(x-n_{b-1})$, we need found $P(1, d+1)$
$P(a,a+1)$ is O(1) operation
if $2 | b-a$, let $c = \frac{a+b}{2}$ and $P(a,b) = P(a,c)P(c,b)$ 
in another case, $P(a,b) = P(a, b-1)P(b-1, b)$

Comment: Thank you, could you please provide a little bit of explanation please ? Appreciated

Comment: It is a calculation order with useing only the operations we are already have.  If power is even - we use divide-and-concqueror  and unite results by fast multiplication. If power is odd - we reduce power to 1

Comment: So this is a final answer or a first step to resolve the problem ?
And do you have a simplified one ? Because I can't even understand the algorithm..

Comment: You need only:
1. Write a pseudocode
2. Get a complexity of this algorithm